# creating undirected graph from directed graph

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just too confused, and can't come up with proper way to do this:

I have this directed graph:
[image]

and have two dictionaries, which show outgoing and incoming scores

```
graph_to = {'a':{'b':2,'c':3},'b':{'a':1,'d':4}}
graph_from = {'a':{'b':1},'b':{'a':2},'c':{'a':3},'d':{'b':4}}
```

For example, in `graph_to`, node `a` goes to node `b` with score 2 and to node `c` with score 3; and in `graph_from` node `a` receives score 1 from node `b`.

I want to create `undirected graph` such that scores between two nodes are summed up. It should become this dictionary:

```
graph = {
    'a':{'b':3,'c':3},
    'b':{'a':3,'d':4},
    'c':{'a':3},
    'd':{'b':4}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to make a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects, and sum the edge counts as you iterate both graph dicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

graph_to = {'a':{'b':2,'c':3},'b':{'a':1,'d':4}}
graph_from = {'a':{'b':1},'b':{'a':2},'c':{'a':3},'d':{'b':4}}

undirected_graph = defaultdict(Counter)

def sum_edges(graph, result):
    for node, edges in graph.items():
        for edge in edges:
            result[node][edge] += edges[edge]

sum_edges(graph_to, undirected_graph)
sum_edges(graph_from, undirected_graph)

pprint(undirected_graph)
```

Which gives:

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
            {'a': Counter({'b': 3, 'c': 3}),
             'b': Counter({'d': 4, 'a': 3}),
             'c': Counter({'a': 3}),
             'd': Counter({'b': 4})})
```

**Note:** `Counter` and `defaultdict` are subclasses of `dict`, so you can treat them the same as normal dictionaries.

If you really want normal dictionaries in the final undirected graph, you can use either of these dict comprehensions:

```
dict((k, dict(v)) for k, v in undirected_graph.items())
# {'a': {'b': 3, 'c': 3}, 'b': {'a': 3, 'd': 4}, 'c': {'a': 3}, 'd': {'b': 4}}

{k: dict(v) for k, v in undirected_graph.items()}
# {'a': {'b': 3, 'c': 3}, 'b': {'a': 3, 'd': 4}, 'c': {'a': 3}, 'd': {'b': 4}}
```

Additionally, you can also use [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) here to refactor `sum_edges()`:

```
def sum_edges(graph, result):
    for node, edges in graph.items():
        result[node].update(edges)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope we appreciate taking things in own hand, here's with simple logic

```
    out_dict = {}
    for key in graph_to : 
        for sub_key in graph_to[key]:
            if  key in graph_from and sub_key in graph_from[key]:
                    out_dict[key] = {sub_key: graph_to[key][sub_key] + graph_from[key][sub_key]}
            else:
                    out_dict[key].update({sub_key: graph_to[key][sub_key]})
    graph_from.update(out_dict)
    print(graph_from)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': 3, 'c': 3}, 'b': {'a': 3, 'd': 4}, 'c': {'a': 3}, 'd': {'b': 4}}
```